# Magento2- How to update an extension to a new version?

Tags: magento2, module

I have my extension in `app/code`. The extension name is `Mirasvit_Seo`.

I want to update it to the latest version. I simply ran `composer update` but it didn't got upgraded. I tried doing this [link](https://mirasvit.com/docs/module-seo/current/setup/upgrade) but got an error showing :

> [InvalidArgumentException]

Could not find a matching version of package `mirasvit/module-seo`. Check the package spelling, your version constraint and that the package is available in a stability which matches your minimum-stability (stable).

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: I think you need to change 2 or 3 files.

Comment: 1. "version": "1.0.0" in composer file. 2. setup_version="1.0.0" in module.xml   please and try again

Answer (score 2):

If this module is paid extension then you can contact your extension provider in your case Mirasvit, you can log in with your credentials in Mirasvit MyAccount and download the latest version for SEO extension.

If you haven't customized in your current module then you can simply replace an updated module in your app/code or if you customize in your current module then you need to pick that customization in the updated module which mirasvit will provide.

For the Composer update, the issue needs more details or you can contact the extension provider for the quick response.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply @Sanjay, is there any way to update the module other than downloading the latest version and place it in app/code.

Comment: Hi @SidharthSatheesh, first you need to check with extension provider, is they provide extension update through composer or not ? 

If they provide then you need the exact component name and its version which will use in composer CLI command like this : composer require <component-name>:<version> --no-update

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below step and check then.

1. "version": "1.0.0" in composer file.
2. setup_version="1.0.0" in module.xml

If you want to direct change please follow.

https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/howtos/install-components.html

and this one.

https://www.magestore.com/magento-installation/how-to-update-magento-extension

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this artical: https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/howtos/install-components.html